# hard code shortcode only on specific category

Tags: shortcode, conditional-tags

I am looking to embed several shortcodes into my post template, but I want the tags to be conditional to a specific category (and subcats).

I've looked through the codex, but I'm unsure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're embedding the code directly into the template file, why bother with shortcodes?

Simply extract the code from the `add_shortcode()` function call, and add it to your template, wrapped in an appropriate conditional tag, such as `in_category()`, e.g.:

```
if ( in_category( $cat ) ) {
     // put shortcode code here
}
```

Note: the `$cat` argument can be an ID, name, or slug.

Comment: I'll be using the template tag for the shortcode, I just put that in to explain. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jason Instead of copy&past the shortcode code, you could use `echo do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]');` to call the shortcode in your conditional statement.